# Cartopy animation with matplotlib - clearing map between each frame?

Tags: animation, matplotlib, cartopy

I assume I'm missing a really simple/basic bit of code somewhere but would appreciate it if someone could tell me where this is going wrong.

```
subplot_kw = dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 12), subplot_kw=subplot_kw)


def animate(i):
    print(i)
    filename = filenames[i]
    print(filename)
    output = read_data(filename)
    lat = output['lat']
    lon = output['lon']

    ax.set_extent([lon_min, lon_max, lat_min, lat_max])

    land_50m = cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '50m')
    ocean_50m = cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', '50m')
    ax.add_feature(ocean_50m, zorder=0, facecolor=sns.xkcd_rgb['bluish'])
    ax.add_feature(land_50m, zorder=0, edgecolor='black', facecolor=sns.xkcd_rgb['moss green'])
    img1 = ax.scatter(lon, lat, c=lat, s=0.05, alpha=1)

    return(img1)



anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 3)
```

This almost works but it results in the animation containing all of the previous frames data as well as you can see below. How do I make clear the map between frames?

[image]

Update:

I think I've resolved this now and it was related to not updating the scatter object but instead I was adding a new one each time.

Following the example here https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/rain.html I used

```
img1.set_array(lat)
img1.set_offsets(np.vstack((lon, lat)).T)
```

which updated the scatter object and worked.

[image]

Comment: A [mcve] would sure be helpful here.

Comment: I was thinking more that the issue is due to my misunderstanding how the animation workflow should work. Any trivial example using scatter should be applicable. I'll add something to the original post.

Comment: Given your update @Rob, I recommend answering  your own question (and marking it as answered). StackOverflow actively supports  users answering their own questions.

Comment: I agree with @pelson. And if you don't, someone will soon